# calling rest api with requestbody and authenticationprincipal

Tags: java, rest, spring-boot, junit, spring-security

I have a rest api which has role based access to its http POST method. It uses spring-security to access api only for authorized users.

I have 2 questions,

1. how external client can pass request body and user object (@AuthenticationPrincipal) to make this api call
2. How can I write junit to test below piece of code,

   `@PreAuthorize("hasAuthority('ADMIN')")
     @PostMapping("/api/access/submit")
     public ResponseEntity<OrderAdminResponse> create(@RequestBody OrderAdminRequest orderAdminSubmitRequest,@AuthenticationPrincipal UserObject user) 
   {
       return ResponseEntity.accepted().body(orderService.submit(orderAdminSubmitRequest));
     }`

My User Object is below,

```
<code>

    public class UserObject {
    private final String name;
    private final String id;
    private final String email;

    private UserObject(String name, int id, String email){
    this.name = name; this.id = id; this.email = email
    }

    public Collection<String> getRoles() {
    return 
    (Collection)this.getAuthorities().stream()
    .map(GrantedAuthority::getAuthority).collect(Collectors.toList());
     }

    public boolean isUserInRole(String role) {
    return this.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch((a) -> {
        return a.getAuthority().equals(role);
    })
    }
   }
 </code>
```

Answer (score 1):

The controller will automatically populate the Authentication Principal, when you make a request with an authenticated user.
For example, if you are using HTTP basic authentication to secure your endpoint, then the principal will be populated from the `Authorization` header. Your request body remains the same regardless of whether you are extracting the principal or not.

An easy way to test your controller is to use the support provided by Spring Security.
If you are using `MockMvc`, one option is to use a post processor to call your endpoint with different types of users.

```
this.mvc.perform(post("/api/access/submit")
    .content("...")
    .with(user("user").roles("USER")))
    .andExpect(status().isUnauthorized());
```

```
this.mvc.perform(post("/api/access/submit")
    .content("...")
    .with(user("admin").roles("ADMIN")))
    .andExpect(status().isOk());
```

You can learn more about Spring Security test support in the documentation [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-security/site/docs/5.1.6.RELEASE/reference/htmlsingle/#test-mockmvc).

Comment: thanks...i think we are close. I am having issues on ".with(user("admin").roles("ADMIN")))" part. I get type conversion error for 'RequestPostProcessor" class.

Comment: I have added my UserObject class for reference.